# Why does `std::pair` take `std::tuple` as ctor argument type rather than `const std::tuple&`?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, constructor, parameter-passing

The C++11 standard defines a constructor of `std::pair` as follows:

```
template<class... Args1, class... Args2>
pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
     std::tuple<Args2...> second_args);
```

Why does `std::pair` take `std::tuple` as ctor argument type rather than `const std::tuple&` ?

What if it is heavy to copy first_args and second_args?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intention is for those tuples to be tuples of references, as created by [`std::forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple):

```
Foo x;
Bar y(1, 2, true);

std::pair<A, B> p(std::piecewise_construct,
                  std::forward_as_tuple(10, x, make()),
                  std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(y), false, get(), 'a'));
```

This constructs pair elements as if by `A(10, x, make())` etc.

The actual tuple types are `std::tuple<int &&, Foo &, Z &&>` etc., which are light-weight.

Comment: uh, am I out? the C++ 11 standard allow us to define an reference to an reference? like this  int && a;??

Comment: @ZhiweiChen no no no no no.... Look up "r-value references" to find out what `&&` means.  It means a specific thing, but _not_ a reference to a reference.

Comment: @ZhiweiChen Me too...  But I'm trying!  `&&` introduces some great ideas, BTW.